# 2D video editing + Blender VSE + GPU?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, gpu

I'm a small-time YouTuber, and I use the Blender VSE to edit / render my vid's. I'm currently running this on my laptop, but—especially if I apply transformations or multiple over-drop layers—rendering is slooooow! Would getting a box with a supported GPU help me get shorter render times? (And, is there a list of supported / recommended GPUs somewhere?) To be clear, everything I'm doing is 2D and via the VSE. I have a background in computing (so I'm not frightened by matrix transformations or technical terminology), but I don't understand what Blender's capabilities are vis-à-vis using a GPU to do 2D compositing.

While we're at it, it *seems* that if I, say, chain ten transform layers it's *substantially* slower than applying one … Why is this‽ I.e., I'd imagine that you'd multiply all of the transform matrices together *once*, cache that, and then apply it to each frame (in which case N transforms ought to take no longer than 1. To be more technically precise, I would expect that applying the *same* N transformations to M frames would take O(N + M) but it, empirically, seems to take O(N * M).).

//cheers

~K.D.P.Ross

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47616/vse-playback-frame-rate-drops-down-with-effects/48038#48038