# Does the FPS of the playback matter?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm trying to edit a video to post on to Youtube and i need the FPS to be 30 so that the audio syncs with the video. In order for me to achieve 30 fps in some parts of the video I have to turn the quality way down. (10% of 720p).

My question is, even if the playback FPS is low, will the render be OK?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47616/vse-playback-frame-rate-drops-down-with-effects/48038#48038

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the render will be fine.  Make sure however that you bump up the quality back up to 100%, otherwise it will (just a guess) render an animation 72x128 pixels.  Playback FPS is just the *realtime* playback speed.  Do keep in mind that your computer may not progress through the render very quickly though.

Comment: Thanks man. I ended up putting up a fairly poor quality video yesterday because of this. Also, what render settings should I use?

Comment: @KeyboardLamp  That's a bit opinion based, but I use MPEG (RGB) with the Quicktime format and H.264 encoding and a bitrate of 2000-3000.  This is (as far as I can tell) lossless, but it can take a while to export.  If you use MPEG-4 encoding, it will go faster (8x speedup I think) but you need to make sure that your bitrate is higher.  All of this requires experimentation.  Not to plug, but if you check my profile, you can find a link to my channel where you can see some videos (5-6 months and newer) that were done in Blender.