# VSE playback drops down

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, transforms, edit-mode, transparency

Im Overlaying/ Over Dropping my face onto a video i want. im a beginner so i dont know if ive just done something wrong in the process but ill try to be precise.

ok, so the frames and resolution for both files are different so i set in the properties bar to the gameplays resolution/positioning at 1280px720p at 29.97fps

what ive done is ive added the first file witch is the game im playing (1280px720p, 29fps) 
ive then add my face (1920x1080p at 29fps), I split all the vid and audio files so that they are all at the same length, i then transformed the vid of my face, scale it down, position it where i want and over drop it over the game.

sounded right to me right??... I dont know, but after i did all the processes it played horridly, then id let it play through and on the second round play at 30 fps for about 10 sec then drop down to 20 or less.

I cant figure out why it does this...

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47616/vse-playback-frame-rate-drops-down-with-effects/48038#48038