# Imported Image strip has really low FPS

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I am working on some stuff for videos I want to make, and am coming close to my goal.

However, after I rendered an intro I made, when I try to scrub or play the image strip in the sequence editor, it runs at about 1 FPS(It was rendered at 24).

- The resolution is 1920*1080.
- Windows 8.1
- 12 GB of RAM with 3000 mb allocated in the system memory cash option.
- I have clicked refresh sequencer.
- I opened the strip in both the blend file I created it in, and a fresh one - same result.
- The images are png files.

Any ideas? If you need more info let me know.

-CAA

Comment: Are the the images the same size as the desired output?  Did you play the timeline once so that the images are cached?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47616/vse-playback-frame-rate-drops-down-with-effects/48038#48038

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for your reply. Yes, I let it play all the way through twice. And yes, that resolution is my default, so it should output to 1920 * 1080.

Answer (score 1):

You should use proxy when working with video editor.

[image]