# How to Draw Waveform Automatically

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I'm doing some video editing in Blender, and every time I drop a clip in to edit, I always find myself selecting the audio and then telling Blender to draw the waveform using *Adjust → Sound → Display Waveform*:

[image: waveform screenshot]

Is there a setting where I can make it automatically draw the waveforms for all audio clips that are pulled into the VSE?

Comment: In the VSE's *View* menu there's a point for *Waveform drawing*. You can set it to always on there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have one or multiple Sound strips you can check *Draw Waveform* in the Strips *Sound* Properties (on the right, open VSE's Properties Panel pressing the <kbd>N</kbd> key) per Strip.

When you want to set the behaviour for all Strips you can do so since the work on the [gooseberry branch](https://gooseberry.blender.org/gooseberry-tools-the-new-improved-sequencer/). They introduced this Feature there directly in the VSE's Menu Bar, but later implemented it in the Master Branch into the *View* menu with an own submenu *Waveform Drawing* where you can switch between two global options for turning Waveforms *On* or *Off* for all strips or let each strip determine on it's on property as described above whether or not to display its Waveform via *Use Strip Option*.
*(You can script this if needed)*

[image: Example of Waveform Drawing options]